# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UpdatePasswordPage: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

All These imported correctly, in

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } 
from 'ionic-angular';
import { Config } from '../../config/config';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UtilitiesProvider } from '../../providers/utilities/utilities';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular/components/toast/toast-controller';
import { DbServiceProvider } from '../../providers/db-service/db-service';
```

Page Constructor is,

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public menuCtrl: MenuController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public config : Config, public utility: UtilitiesProvider,public toastCtrl: ToastController,public dbService: DbServiceProvider)
```

Now, In the Error, the **?** is for the last object which dbService.

there are some other pages which coded similarly and working file.

every provider is working well, only this is not working on this particular page.

Note, Page is included in app.module.ts properly.

if I remove that dbProvider, it works fine. but I need that to call a function of that and do some process.

can anyone help and guide

here is my environment details

Ionic:

```
  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0
  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
```

Cordova:

```
  cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova- 
  lib@8.1.1)
  Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, browser 
  5.0.1
  Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic- 
  webview 1.1.1, (and 18 other plugins)
```

System:

```
  NodeJS : v7.8.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
  npm    : 4.2.0
  OS     : Linux 3.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import ToastController like this!

```
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
```